# Javascript var not working in calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

The line 11 wont call 'l' as the value. If I put the value directly in the JS it works...

```js
$(function() {
  $('#calculate').on('click', function() {
    var b = parseInt($('#b').val().trim()),
      l = parseInt($('#l').val().trim()),
      m = parseInt($('#m').val().trim()),
      p = parseInt($('#p').val().trim()),
      w = parseInt($('#w').val().trim()),
      ppw,
      d;
    d = b * (1 / m) * 1000;
    w = (l * 1000) / d;
    ppw = p / w;
    $('#d').val(d);
    $('#w').val(w);
    $('#ppw').val(ppw);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
bucket <input id='b' type='text' value='10' /><br/>
liters <input id='l' type='text' value='0.473' /><br/>
mix <input id='m' type='text' value='500' /><br/>
price <input id='p' type='text' value='229' /><br/>

<button id='calculate'>Calculate</button><br/>
dillute: <input id='d' type='text' /><br/>
washes: <input id='w' type='text' /><br/>
price pr wash:<input id='ppw' type='text' />
```

New to JS, so if I'm doing anything weird, its my first time actually doing JS by myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l` contains a string that represents floating point number, but you are trying to parse it as an integer.  This truncates the value to 0.  Try `parseFloat` instead:

```
l = parseFloat($('#l').val().trim()),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `l` value is not an integer, it's a float number between 0 and 1.

If you use `parseInt`, it will be rounded down to an integer, hence 0 in your case. You should use `parseFloat` to get the "real" value

```
l = parseFloat($('#l').val().trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the value in litres is a decimal use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`. (Using `parseInt` was rounding it off to Zero)

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tay3hus5/